# Side bar is lag when scrolling?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I just built my first [website](http://ianxo.000webhostapp.com) using flexbox.  but the sidebar seems to have a small problem on **cellphone**. I don't know how to explain it so I'm gonna post a screenshot.

[image: Screenshot] as you can see there is a white space at the top-left corner. However it only happens in the first few pixels, if I keep scrolling the white space disappears. No problem [image: here].

Comment: What kind of phone are you using? I'm not seeing this problem on my end. I checked firefox, chrome, safari, and my iphone 6s.

Comment: @davidatthepark Note 5 with samsung browser

Comment: @davidatthepark can u try scrolling fast?

Comment: I tried but still not seeing it. Have you tried different browsers on the Note 5?

Comment: @davidatthepark yeah the same problem with chrome

Comment: A hacky solution I can think of is to give the aside a top of -100px. Seems to be a device-specific bug I can't duplicate.

Comment: @davidatthepark seems like margin-top:-300px; for the aside solved the problem